# PHP '../X.php include doesn't work, needs full path..?

Tags: php

For some reason, my include ../ isn't working for me, or perhaps not the way i want it to work.

Instead of: for example

`'../lib/common.php'`, I'd need to use the full path. Which becomes

`'C:/XXX/htdocs/lib/common.php'`,

this does the job, but i have over 100s of these `'../lib/common.php'` in my code, which means i need to rewrite all of them. What's going wrong?

I've tried

```
<?php 
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/yourpath/yourfile.php";
   include_once($path);
?>
```

but it essentially did nothing.

Comment: Can you give an example of the associated file hierarchy of the calling code?

Answer (score 0):

> but i have over 100s of these '../lib/common.php' in my code, which
>   means i need to rewrite all of them.

Why not autoincluding the complete folder.

```
foreach(glob('C:/XXX/htdocs/lib/*.php') as $fileName) {
   include_once($fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't recommend you to write the complete path. I use "__DIR__" which denotes the directory **where the file is placed**. Because if you wish to change the path of your project whenever you don't worry about your code it will work!.

The problem is '../lib/common.php' this means fetch the file with respect to the current directory where you are running for example, if you are in /var/www, "../" will denote /var.

Comment: @Progrock its case insensitive give it a try,

Comment: well I never.  Blushes.